# Angularjs - Loading JSON data with $scope values (dynamic) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have ng-model to my input field like below.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="FirstName">
        {{FirstName}}
</div>
```

Now in my controller `console.log $scope.FirstName` is the correct values I give in my view.

But when I try to load the `$scope` into a **JSON** like structure I get undefined.

```
myApp.controller('GlobalCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.loadedata = {"asd":$scope.FirstName};
    console.log($scope.FirstName); //this is fine
    console.log($scope.loadedata); //but this is undefined.
});
```

Now `$scope.loadedata)` is **undefined**. why is it? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did get my values in string format. And I am fine with `$scope.FirstName` but my problem is with `$scope.loadedata` still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My view:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="req.FirstName">
    {{req.FirstName}}
</div>
```

My Controller :

```
myApp.controller('GlobalCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.req = {};
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.req));
});
```

After a long research, I found out that it's better to do without serializing and you can do like this using ng-model. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things about your code snippet. You are using an input bar where your DOM is trying to render FirstName which is undefined. See this demo for the proper us of the input and two-way binding template-controller relationship.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Also, where are you calling the console.log()? I assume after the controller call?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Made few edits. Please check it now.